# Enforce SqlConnection to be open for specified duration

Tags: .net, sqlconnection, lifetime

It seems that SqlConnections close after some period of time of inactivity. I need to be able to control for how long the connection remains open. There is a "connection timeout" and "Connection Lifetime" properties that can be configured for connections, but they do not do what I need.

The problem is that our application is huge and in lots of places connections don't get closed when some screens are open. A user can open a screen, then go to lunch, then come back, then try to do something and get a "connection has been lost" exception. I know that it is an antipattern, but for now it would be easier to extend the connection lifetime in one place, then to open/close and pool connections in thousands of places.

Comment: The answer is to fix your application so it closes connections after using them. What you are looking for does not exist - connection timeouts are the only other option.

Answer (score 0):

You are designing your app very wrong.  Connections should never stay open for any longer than a single set of queries (that is, the queries needed for a single operation).  Don't worry, there is no performance issue as SqlConnection internally pools connections based on connection string.  So even if you open and close a connection, the REAL connection will stay open for a period of time.

What's more, internally, if the connection is closed, then the pooler will re-open it when needed, so you don't have to worry about it.

Seriously, just open and close your connections as you use them.  That's how it's supposed to work.

FYI, the reason the connections are closed is that the internal connection pooler will "reclaim" connections that have been open for a long time.  So what you're doing by keeping the connections open is fighting the connection pooler.

Comment: @usr - good catch, I meant a single logical operation, which could include multiple queries.

Answer (score 0):

Connections don't close automatically. Something has failed, like the network.

That is expected, though. Don't hold connections open! You are working against how the system was meant to be used, and you'll suffer for it.

Change the app so that it uses one connection per unit of work, and the closes it. As a band-aid fix, ensure that `SqlConnection.State` is `Open` before executing a query.

Comment: actually, the connection pooler will reclaim open connections after a period of time.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @MystereMan only when you have returned them to the pool by closing them. As long as you hold your SqlConnection object open, nobody is closing it from under you. That would be horrible! It would unpredictably abort transactions. It would potentially inject failures into any query and cause availability problems.

Comment: it may be horrible and unpredictable, but it's what happens.  Read the link I sent you.  "The connection pooler periodically scans connection pools looking for unused connections that were not closed by Close or Dispose, and reclaims those it finds."  and "The connection pooler removes a connection from the pool after it has been idle for an extended period of time, or if the pooler detects that the connection with the server has been severed."

Comment: It reclaims connections if the app has removed the last reference to the SqlConnection object. As long as the app holds a reference to it, it will not be GC'ed and the framework will not reclaim the connection. After it has been GC'ed it is, of course, reclaimed, because anything else would be a resource leak. That does not break the app though because the app does not know of the connection anymore. It has deliberately abandoned it (even though it should have disposed of it first).

Comment: you're confusing the pooled connection with the SqlConnection.  No, the SqlConnection is not reclaimed, the physical database connection is reclaimed.  SqlConnection uses a pooled set of connections that are managed by a connection pooler.

Comment: I understand this. The SqlConnection is the application-visible handle to an underlying connection. Handle destroyed (or connection severed) => internal connection reclaimed. Not earlier.

Comment: that's in direct conflict with MS's documentation which says explicitly that it reclaims *OPEN* connections that have been idle for a period of time.  A connection can't be open if it's destroyed, since garbage collection will call the finalizer which will close the connection if there are no references to it.  The connection scavenger has no way of knowing if an open connection is because someone has a reference to it or not.  Only the GC can know that, and if the GC knows that, it will have already called close.  Your interpretation doesn't make sense vs the docs.

Comment: I have posed a question on this looking for an authoritative answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664317/will-pooled-sql-connections-be-scavaged-if-there-is-still-a-reference-to-them

Answer (score -1):

Its not good programming to open connection so long. Open connection whenever need and close to after completion of database task. If you feel it will impact on your application performance then use connection pooling

Comment: Thanks, cap. I've said the same thing in my question.